# Using ngCordova with Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to use ngCordova for my cordova app however, I am getting `device` is undefined when calling the below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCordova'])...

app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $cordovaDevice) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
    $cordovaDevice.getPlatform(); // console.log or something.
    });
```

Everything is included correctly and the plugin is installed. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Where do you declare `device`? Post more code.

Comment: Are your executing these code on mobile or on desktop? device will be available when you execute this code on mobile after executing cordova build command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `deviceready` event before accessing any of the ngCordova plugins

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaDevice.getPlatform();
}, false);
```